# useGuards in nestjs for security measures

Tags: nestjs

Currently I have a /users route which has protected routes using a auth guard which check the validity of jwt token

there is a module for chargebee (similar to stripe) whcih has its own route /chargebee
in which there is a checkout function, which requires the user id and the plan and returns a page link

so i wanted to know how should i secure this route
i should just use this auth guard and take the id from the jwt
or should i create a new guard maybe called permission guard , and from the frontend send the id plus the plan selected

which is more secure ?
Or maybe something else ?

Thinking of using this permission guard to check if the id from jwt plus the id in body matches then only that user is allowed to  create checkout page